# Netbeans C++ additional commands (using tolua++)

Tags: c++, netbeans, lua

I am building a C++ project that uses tolua++ for binding.

When building 'by hand'. at the command line, I am entering the following command:

```
tolua++5.1 -o ../src/LuaBinding.cpp -H LuaBinding.h Binding.pkg
```

I don't know where to enter this command line in the Netbeans IDE.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you created the project, you might have a Makefile. (For example, if when creating the project, you selected "C/C++ Application" then NetBeans created a Makefile for you.)

In the *Project* pane, you would have a node called *Important Files*, and in there should be *Makefile*. I am assuming you can put what commands you need into the Makefile. The makefile NetBeans gives you in *Important Files* actually allows you to augment its own standard makefile targets by adding commands to the pre and post targets. To get more control over the make process you could replace NetBeans' make files with a completely custom set. That would mean that you would need to hook up your own targets to menu commands--not rocket science but beyond the scope of this answer.

If it is more general than that... if all files are built with tolua++, then you can establish it Build Tools Tool Collection. Click on *Tools*, then *Options*, then click on the *C/C++* icon in the Options dialog's toolbar, and then on the *Build Tools* tab. In that case, the standard NetBeans makefile (or whatever custom makefile you've provided) will simply use that without having to muck through the makefile itself.